# how to create particular shell without using execution event

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have two classes of a plugin which are responsible for executing the same plugin from in a popup menu and menu item. But since one of them has run() method I can not use the execution event for creating a shell.
How do I overcome this issue

```
public class ConvertConstantsToEnumHandler extends AbstractHandler {


 //execution of the plugin
 public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {


  ISelection currentSelection = HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelectionChecked(event);

  RefactoringMenuAction menuitem= new RefactoringMenuAction();
  menuitem.setEvent(event);
  List selectedFields = getSelectedFields(currentSelection);


   Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveShellChecked(event);

   //get the selected Fields to do the convertion
   IField[] fields = (IField[]) selectedFields.toArray(new IField[] {});
   try {
    ConvertConstantsToEnumWizard.startConvertConstantsToEnumRefactoring(fields, shell);
   } catch (JavaModelException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  return null;
 }


public class RefactoringMenuAction implements IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate {
 public IWorkbenchWindow window;

 public RefactoringMenuAction() {
 }

 public void run(IAction action) {
  RefactoringPlugin rp = new RefactoringPlugin();
 try {
   rp.start(rp.getTheBundle()); // get the current context of the eclipse
  } catch (CoreException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

// here I need to find a way to access or create a shell to compile same as the above class
 }
```

Comment: Can you please reformat your question so that the code snippet appears as formatted code? I think CTRL+k can do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to execute the same piece of code, why are you doing it via action in one place and with command in another place? Why can't you simply use one command and add a command contribution in both the places?